# Are there any techniques to separate HTML structure from the underlying data?

Tags: javascript, html, httprequest, httpresponse

Database access is often the slowest part of an application, so to accommodate that are there any techniques to respond to a request by:

1. sending a static HTML structure
2. running a query on the data store
3. once the data returns from the query, then push the data to the client (perhaps in JSON)
4. use JavaScript to update the HTML by adding text or changing value attributes

First, is this a bad idea?  Having not found anything resembling this in my research over the last couple days I assume it is a bad one.  However, if it is not, is it possible? And are there established techniques for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has already been said, this is basically what an "ajax application" is. They are very easy to write nowadays, mostly because of the number of frameworks out there.

Check out http://sproutcore.com, http://javascriptmvc.com/ and http://cappuccino.org/ Those are "heavyweight" solutions, but depending on what you are building, that may suit your needs perfectly.

If those don't look like the sort of thing you want, I would take a look at http://dojotoolkit.org It is a javascript framework that pretty much handles everything you could imagine wanting to do in an integrated sort of way.

If you are already using jquery, the best bet may be something like http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/, or http://knockoutjs.com/, or http://sammyjs.org/.

Comment: I was aware of AJAX and use it, but usually it supplements the process.  What I've worked with is in general, a user sends a request, server retrieves data and compiles it into a template and then returns the combined result.  In the brief time I've had to look over your links I think they make AJAX more central to how the site operates and that's exactly what I want.  This is a lot of information and I think you have me pointed in the right direction.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/

http://stanlemon.net/projects/jquery-templates.html